# TS insists my `useMemo` function returns `null[]`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The function below does *not* return `null[]` but despite any definitions I give the function is shows an error that the function returns `null[]`. What is the reason for this?

```
const attributionList = React.useMemo<insertTypeHere>(() => {
    return uniqBy(
      flatMap(
        reject(attributions, (v) => v === null),
        (v) => {
          return v;
        }
      ),
      "snapshot.id"
    );
  }, [attributions]);
```

To be clear `insertTypeHere` will not change what TS thinks the function returns.

Comment: Have you tried to give a type to attributionList?  Like `const attributionList : SomeType = ...`?

Comment: No, that does not help, it is also not the way to type a `useMemo` function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was the intialization of `attributions` as null. TS will infer types based in initialization and therefore without casting it will only accept the types as initially set.